# Using Object... in Java

Tags: java, object, generics

I'm trying to evaluate whether to use `Object...` in my method parameters when I know what those parameters should be. It seems like I could use `Object...` for just about anything.

For example, I could write this:

```
public Object processObject(Object... obj)  {
    final TreeDetails treeDetails = (TreeDetails) obj[0];
    final FlowerDetails flowerDetails = (FlowerDetails) obj[1];
}
```

In this case what would the initialized contents of the array be?

Is there a better (e.g. perhaps more type safe, or avoiding exceptions, or ...) way of writing this?

Comment: (My vote was "unclear," not opinion-based.)

Comment: I'm hoping my edit is sufficient to reopen

Comment: "It seems like I could use Object... for just about anything." You can, but that's exactly why you shouldn't. Nothing stops me calling it with zero parameters, two strings, 100 Integers.... Your code here requires at least two parameters, the first being an instance of `TreeDetails`, the second being an instance of `FlowerDetails`; you cannot enforce any of these constraints by making the parameter of type `Object...`.

Comment: I am reviewing this code, and thought this is a bad practice. Just trying to valuate the code.

Answer (score 3):

**No it is not**. It is completely unclear what the parameters are supposed to be.

Try instead:

```
public MyReturnType processObject(TreeDetails treeDetails, 
                                  FlowerDetails flowerDetails)  {
    // ...
}
```